# Prevent multiple action bar title changes when navigating with the navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

As per the Android guidelines, I implemented an `ActionBarDrawerToggle` that switches to the global context `onDrawerOpened` and a local context `onDrawerClosed`.  This context switch involves changing the action bar items as well as the action bar title, and is really straightforward. The problem is, if I am navigating to a new screen then the action bar's title will change twice, once for the switch back to local context and again for the new screen that the user is navigating too.  This seems clunky, and I can't seem to figure out a way to implement the title change such that the user doesn't see it twice.

Comment: So, you're selecting an item in your `DrawerLayout`, then the drawer closes which causes a title change, and the title changes once more after you start a new `Activity`? How exactly are you "navigating to a new screen"?

Comment: @adneal That is correct.  I am "navigating to a new screen" by launching an `intent` in `onDrawerClosed` if the selected item is different than the currently selected item.  I've thought about trying to implement a "one activity with dynamic fragment loading" approach, but I think the problem would still remain.  I've checked some apps, such as Imgur, and they accomplish what I am trying to do.  Though, interestingly, the Play store app changes the title twice if you look closely.  It really bothers me though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the best way to handle this is to have a condition you check when the drawer closes.

Here's a short example:

```
private boolean mNoTitleChange;
private int mPosition = -1;

@Override
public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
    if (mNoTitleChange) {
        startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NewActivity.class));
        mNoTitleChange = false;
        return;
    }
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mPosition != -1) {
        setTitle(mYourTitles[mPosition]);
        mPosition = -1;
    }
}
```

Whenever you select an item in your `DrawerLayout`, adjust the `boolean` as needed.

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        mNoTitleChange = true;
        mPosition = position;
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the title won't be correct if you navigate back using the `back button`.

Comment: @mattblang There are a lot of ways around that. I made an edit demonstrating a simple one based off [Google's example](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) But the idea is to save whatever title will be there and load it in `onResume`.

Comment: Perfect.  My implementation is a bit different, but the idea is the same.  I could have swore that changing the title in `onResume` still caused a double change when returning using the back button.  It doesn't though, not sure what I was doing when I thought that.  Thanks again!